# Pandas: Sum down a column based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I've managed to successfully confuse myself with this problem. Here's a sample of my dataframe:

```py
Model  Rank  Prediction  Runtime
 0.05     1    0.516267  250.500
 0.05     2    0.504968  253.875
 0.05     3    0.482915  310.875
 0.05     4    0.470865  251.375
 0.05     5    0.459580  277.250
    .     .           .        .
    .     .           .        .
    .     .           .        .
 0.50    96    0.130696  250.500
 0.50    97    0.130696  220.375
 0.50    98    0.130696  314.625
 0.50    99    0.130696  232.000
 0.50   100    0.130696  258.000
```

And my use case is as follows:

I would, for each `Model`, like to calculate the total `Runtime` with respect to its `Rank`. By that I mean, the `Runtime` at `Rank` 1 should be the sum of all `Runtime`s (for its respective `Model`) and the `Runtime` at `Rank` 100 should be only the `Runtime` for `Rank` 100 (for its respective `Model`).

So for instance,

- If the `Rank` is `1`, the `Runtime` column at that row should represent the total sum of **all** `Runtime`s for `Model` 0.05
- If the `Rank` is 2, it should be **all** of the `Runtime`s for `Model` 0.05 **minus** the `Runtime` for `Model` 0.05 at `Rank` 1
  ...
- If the `Rank` is 100, it should be **only** the `Runtime` for `Model` 0.05 at `Rank` 100.

I have the idea in my head but I'm not sure how this is achieved in Pandas. I know how to sum the column, but not to sum based on a condition like this. If any more data or explanation is required, I'd be happy to attach it.

Comment: Were you helped by any of the answers provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you're asking for is essentially a reversed cumulative sum, which you can do by a reverse, cumsum, reverse operation:

```py
In [4]: df["model_runtimes"] = df[::-1].groupby("Model")["Runtime"].cumsum()[::-1]

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
   Model  Rank  Prediction  Runtime  model_runtimes
0   0.05     1    0.516267  250.500        1343.875
1   0.05     2    0.504968  253.875        1093.375
2   0.05     3    0.482915  310.875         839.500
3   0.05     4    0.470865  251.375         528.625
4   0.05     5    0.459580  277.250         277.250
5   0.50    96    0.130696  250.500        1275.500
6   0.50    97    0.130696  220.375        1025.000
7   0.50    98    0.130696  314.625         804.625
8   0.50    99    0.130696  232.000         490.000
9   0.50   100    0.130696  258.000         258.000
```

Answer (score -2):

I would frame your problem in two steps.

First, each model is independent, so you can split the dataframe by the model field, and solve each one independently. This is a good place to use `groupby()`.

Second, your problem is like a cumulative sum, except that a normal cumulative sum starts at the top and carries the sum down, and you want to do the opposite. You can solve this by reversing the dataframe, or by sorting in descending order.

With that in mind, here's how I would approach this problem. (Lines 1-14 are just setting up the dataset.)

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
# Only used for setting up dataframe. Ignore.
def flatten(t):
    return [item for sublist in t for item in sublist]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Model": flatten([list(c * 20) for c in "ABCDE"]),
    "Rank": flatten([range(1, 21) for i in range(5)]),
    "Prediction": np.random.rand(100),
    "Runtime": np.random.rand(100),
})



def add_sum(d):
    d["Runtime"] = d["Runtime"].cumsum()
    return d

df = df.sort_values(by=["Model", "Rank"], ascending=False) \
    .groupby("Model") \
    .apply(add_sum) \
    .sort_index()

print(df)
```